# PDF Download functionality

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc with jsp. I want to give download to pdf functionality for an article which I see in the view rendered by the jsp. I want to have a same look and feel in the pdf as I have in the jsp view(without the header and footers ofcourse). What is the simplest and the best way to achive this functionality? I'm aware that I can use itext library for AbstractPdf view but that would mean I need to create cell and table. Is there any easier way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I remember right, then iText has a way to render HTML.

So what you need to do, is create the HTML content without header and footer, and then put this in iText.

HTML to PDF:
@see [Using itext to convert HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

JSP to String:
@see [rendering JSP to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464353/rendering-jsp-to-a-string)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the html from jsp? I'm returning modelAndView from my controller.

Comment: I have added a link the a stack overflow question that discuss that theme.