# How to store the result of a JSP in a string?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to store the result of a JSP in a string.

For example, I want to be able to call a function like:

```
String result = ProcessJsp("/jspfile.jsp");
```

Also, this must be rather efficient.  Making a url request to the jsp and then storing it would not work because I am running on the Google App Engine, and I'm not sure how slow that would be and also there is a Quota for the number of url fetches you can make.

How could I do this?

Here are my thoughts on how to do this, though I'm not sure if it would work, and I'm hoping there is something simpler:

Do `RequestDispatcher("/jspfile.jsp").include(hreq, hresp)`, but instead of putting the real HttpResponse object in there, you put your own where the `getWriter()` method returns something that writes to your String or a memory buffer, etc.

Comment: More or less a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152786/looking-for-a-capturing-impl-of-httpservletresponsewrapper

Comment: @Thor It would have to go out to a router and come back right? The reason I am wanting to store it in a String is to speed up my web app by caching parts of my jsps.

Comment: @skaffman Is making an HttpResponseWrapper the only way to do it?

Comment: @Spines: It's the only way that I've found. I'd love to see an alternative, though, because I'm not happy with it.

Comment: @Spines: it is not slow if the URL points to localhost.

Comment: @BalusC +1, True, I'm on the google app engine though and I'm not sure how it would work with that, also there is a quota for the number of url fetches you can do.

Comment: Appengine.. Request quota.. Ouch.. Your best bet would be really a `HttpServletResponseWrapper`. I've posted similar solution before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side/1963571#1963571

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you state that your goal is caching portions of a JSP page. I'll assume that you're using dynamic includes, rather than client-side requests (eg, Ajax).

If the former, your best solution -- rather than write something yourself -- is to follow the instructions for integrating [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/getting_started.html) into your app-server's stack. Or, if you want to write something yourself, follow the same process but create your own caching filter.

If you want to cache content that will be accessed from the client, then I recommend putting a web-server (such as Apache with mod_cache) in front of your app-server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know what method EHCache uses for getting the result of a JSP?

Comment: I gave you a link for a reason.

Comment: Just hoping you knew instead of me searching through their source code.

Comment: If you've already decided that you want to do this on your own, read up on Servlet Filters. That's what EHCache uses.