# capture HttpServletResponse Object

Tags: java, servlets

I want to extract the body of a HttpServletResponse Object.I know we could use a filter to do that but i was wondering if there is any other way in which i can get the body content.I just want to extract the information from my printstream object.Any help or code samples will help?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152786/looking-for-a-capturing-impl-of-httpservletresponsewrapper

Comment: If there was a better way, I would have answered that in your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body If that somehow doesn't work for you, you should elaborate the issue in detail instead of re-asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP to create an aspect around the do**** method and capture the response.