# Spring MVC - AJAX-JSON Response to contain rendered JSP view

Tags: ajax, json, model-view-controller, spring, view

I need my controller to return an AJAX JSON response that contains the updated HTML code.

The updated HTML code is created by rendering a JSP view.

For example:
JSP:

```
<tr>
<td>${data1}</td>
<td>${data2}</td>
</tr>
```

JSON response:

```
{"columns" : "2", "rows":"1", "data":rendered view}
```

Currently I'm trying to create a dummy response with "my own" outputstream and put the rendered view content in the json response, but with no luck.

Other than the fact I can't get this solution to work, it doesn't feel right.
Any tips on the proper way to do it?

Thanks,
Ori

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the view you want to capture is in `/WEB-INF/views/my.jsp`, then call

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/my.jsp").include(request, myResponse);
```

where myResponse is either a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` that you've created, or a Spring `MockHttpServletResponse`.   In the latter case you can get the rendered output from getContentAsString().

EDIT below

I ran into another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152786/looking-for-a-capturing-impl-of-httpservletresponsewrapper) around capturing servlet responses that had some pointers to HttpServletResponseWrappers that you can use.

Two implementations that look good:

1. DWR [SwallowingHttpServletResponse](http://svn.directwebremoting.org/dwr/trunk/core/api/main/java/org/directwebremoting/util/SwallowingHttpServletResponse.java)
2. Sitemesh [PageResponseWrapper](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/api/com/opensymphony/module/sitemesh/filter/PageResponseWrapper.html)

Enjoy,

Comment: Ya... I've created a dummy response that is similar to the mock response, this works but I have two follow up questions:
1) jboss (tomcat)  does a validation that the response used is the actual one, I had to specify a specific system property to disable. any other way?
2) Any way to use ViewResolver to get the URL? When I try to I get an error about application context missing...

Comment: In that case I would try using a HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapping the original response but capturing the output.

Comment: Added links to HttpServletResponseWrappers that you can use.