# Retrieving JSP content from a servlet within a single web application (under Tomcat)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

First of all, I wanna apologize for not so clear description of the question. Let's consider we have some working mechanism for e-mail sending, and we also have some e-mail templates mechanism based on JSP processing engine. Let's say, these templates *may* be directly accessed like http://localhost/app/templates/template1.jsp?k1=v1&k2=v2 and always return an HTML that can be inserted into an e-mail for a certain user in the back-end code. Simply saying, the short-hand code might look like:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>() {{ ..puts.. }};
String message = readJsp("/templates/template1.jsp", parameters); // servlet-context?
sendEMail(recipient, subject, message)
```

Currently I found two solutions for implementing the `readJsp` method. The **first** approach is to make a HTTP request from the servlet to the web-server where both servlet and JSP-template are put at. Well, I'm not a fan of this...

The **second** and much better way that really works is getting a request dispatcher from the servlet context and invoking its `include()` method with the response wrapper (this work around is described [here](http://www.codango.com/jsp/fnc/content-review/?id=5670110)). This method works perfect, but I don't know how I can use this approach if I cannot get a `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` instances (let's consider my `sendEMail()` method can be invoked both from servlet `service` method *[it's easy to get the HttpServletRequest/Response instances here]* and a thread that runs as a part of the web application *[where HttpServletRequest/Response instance are **never** known and even cannot be passed to the thread]*). I can suggest that I can create the `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` instances myself in a certain way, but I don't know how and whether it will be ok for that `readJsp()` method based on the **second** approach.

So, the question is basically about, perhaps, the 3rd (and even better) way of getting the JSP content from a thread that does not belong to a servlet but runs in the same web application. Or is it possible to create valid `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` instances from scratch to make the *second* approach work out of servlet `service()` method?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture generated dynamic content at server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side)

Comment: Also [Spring MVC - AJAX-JSON Response to contain rendered JSP view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489504/spring-mvc-ajax-json-response-to-contain-rendered-jsp-view/5490775#5490775)

Comment: @ericacm, consider I have neither original request nor original response objects because I have a thread that have no way to take the request and request from. And... the JSP outout is not transferred to a client. The JSP output should be put into the e-mail body sent by the sender thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Spring's MockHttpServletRequest/Response but from what I have heard, Tomcat's ServletDispatcher.include() does not work with those.

I would recommend **not** using JSP in the case where you don't have access to a request/response pair.   Instead use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) to template your emails.

Comment: Actually I have chosen the JSP because it can be pretty integrated into the i18n mechanism we implemented in our project (and most JSP pages are already i18n-ed using that). I have a bit experience in FreeMarker, and no in Velocity. But I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: The Velocity engine has been involved, though I still can't get some effects I reached using the JSP engine. Thanks.