# How to generate an archive of multiple pages in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, view, requestdispatcher

I want to allow my users to "bulk export" an archive of selected resources, i.e., http://.../resource/1, resource/2, resource/4, ... ,

My thought was "render the HTML of each page to a string and use java.util.zip to create a multifile archive."

My problem then became "how to get the HTML of a page so that I can loop over them?"

I cannot figure out a way to get a JstlView to render to a String, nor can I see a way to set the ServletOutputStream to be a ZipOutputStream.

My last thought is to actually GET the HTML of each of the resources via HTTP. I imagine that will be easy enough to code, but it seems pretty byzantine. Is there a better way? (Perhaps something with RequestDispatcher.forward()? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [SwallowingHttpServletResponse](http://svn.directwebremoting.org/dwr/trunk/core/api/main/java/org/directwebremoting/util/SwallowingHttpServletResponse.java) from DWR (or a [PageResponseWrapper](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/api/com/opensymphony/module/sitemesh/filter/PageResponseWrapper.html) from Sitemesh) as a parameter to RequestDispatcher.include() and then get the output from that response object.

See my response (no pun intended) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489504/spring-mvc-ajax-json-response-to-contain-rendered-jsp-view/5490775#5490775).

Comment: I used the SwallongHttpServletResponse -- easy as pie.