# Using Spring how do I get contents of HttpServletResponse in postHandle interceptor and in case of error redirect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

All my controllers return JSON response. As part of post handling how do I examine contents of JSON response and in case of errors how do I redirect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152786/looking-for-a-capturing-impl-of-httpservletresponsewrapper

Answer (score 0):

The JSON operations in Spring are based on MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter. If you want to log the result, extend it and override the write method OR use an aspect on this method:

```
@Aspect
 public class MyLogger {

   @Pointcut("execution(org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(..))")
   public void myPointCut() { }

   @AfterReturning(pointcut="myPointCut()",returning="result")
   public void logMethodEntry(JoinPoint jp) {
      ...
   }

}
```

To manage erors, you can use the ExceptionHandler annotation on your methods/classes:

```
@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public Map<String, String> notFoundHandler(Exception e){
    return ...;
}
```

I hope this will help ;)

Comment: Thanks Treydone for your response. What I need to do is inspect contents of JSON message generated by MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and based on the status need to redirect. I am not clear how will PointCut help me here?