# modify response parameters with servlet filter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

I'm working on a project which I need to perform a function `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(String htmlString)` on both all request and response parameters. 
For [changing request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter) I've used `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, but for changing response values, I could n't find any clue.

Comment: Use a `HttpServletResponseWrapper`?

Comment: It have to do the same thing, but it has not any parameter related function inside. If there is any, let me know.

Comment: You should find an example of implementation in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157590/3545273)